# How to set color of the Back icon of Form's Toolbar?

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to change color of all elements of form's toolbar:

```
public class LoginForm extends Form{

    private Form formSplash;
    
    public LoginForm(Resources theme) {
        super("Login", new BorderLayout());
        setUIID("rush-login");
        getToolbar().getTitleComponent().setUIID("rush-login-title");
        getToolbar().getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0);
        getToolbar().setBackCommand("Back", e -> {
                    if(formSplash != null) {
                        formSplash.showBack();
                    }
        });
        setScrollable(false);
    }

    public void setFormSplash(Form formSplash) {
        this.formSplash = formSplash;
    }
}
```

I do see the title's color changed, but the back icon still has the original color:

[image: title with back button]

Is any way to have the same color for each element of the toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work for `setBackCommand` but you can use `findCommandComponent` on the toolbar and set the UIID to whatever you want:

```
Button b = toolbar.findCommandComponent(cmd);
```

`setBackCommand` returns a `Command` object you should be able to use for that although you might need to use the add command to left side methods instead for this use case.

Comment: Shai, I was able to find the button, but then I've set `b.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0x4A4A4A);` it didn't affect the color of the icon. Also, Iv'e tried to set text for the button: `b.setText("HELLO");` and the color applied on the text, but the icon still was in original color. I assume that there is a global color for such toolbar icons, I don't mind changing it on the global level, but I couldn't find the way how to do this. Is it even possible?

Comment: The icon is a material design icon and as such it takes the color on the moment of creation. That means you'll need to call `FontImage` to set the icon over again if you want to change the color.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the color of the material icons can be changed from the theme editor, adjusting the Default Style for the foreground color. But this only works, when you don't activate the CN1 css support.

In case you use the css support or you want to use a different icon, here is a working example for styling material icons and, especially, the back command:

```
Form my Form = new Form ();     
int color = 0xffffff;
Font materialFontBack = Font.createTrueTypeFont("fontello-back", "fontello-back.ttf");           
FontImage imageBack = FontImage.createFixed("\ue800", materialFontBack, color, 40, 40);


Command back = new Command("Back") {

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
             formStart.showBack();
     }
};

myForm.getToolbar().setBackCommand(back);

ToolBar myToolbar = myForm.getToolbar();
Button buttonToolbar = myToolbar.findCommandComponent(back);
buttonToolbar.setIcon(imageBack);
```

A guide on how to import font images is [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-icon-fonts-such-as-fontello.html).